# How to write sql query to get the below result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with below data.

[image: actual table data]

And the expected result will be below data.

[image: Expected table data]

Here step1 completion date is arrival date of step2 and the step2 completion date is arrival date of step3.

How to write SQL query to get this result.

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

This Script gives your expected Result

```
;With Cte(
id,StepName,ArrivalDate,duedate
)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'Step1','25/12/2017','1/1/2018' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Step2','26/12/2017','1/1/2018' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Step3','27/12/2017','1/1/2018' 
)
SELECT
     id
     ,StepName
     ,ArrivalDate
     ,duedate
     ,ISNULL(LEAD(ArrivalDate,1)OVER(ORDER BY ArrivalDate),'') AS CompletionDate
FROM CTE
```

Result

```
id  StepName    ArrivalDate duedate    CompletionDate
-----------------------------------------------------
1   Step1       25/12/2017  1/1/2018    26/12/2017
2   Step2       26/12/2017  1/1/2018    27/12/2017
3   Step3       27/12/2017  1/1/2018
```

Answer (score 0):

This should serve your purpose, completion date as startdate from next id

```
SELECT x.id
    ,x.stepname
    ,x.arrival_date
    ,x.due_date
    ,isnull(y.arrival_date, '') Completion_date
FROM x
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id
        ,step1
        ,step2
        ,arrival_date
    FROM x
    ) y ON x.id = y.id + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a row number based on ascending order of `id` column.(If `id` column has any gaps). Then use a `LEFT JOIN` / `RIGHT JOIN` with `rn = rn + 1`.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        order by [id]
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select t1.[stepName], t1.[ArrivalDate], t1.[dueDate], 
coalesce(t2.[dueDate], '') as [completiondate]
from cte t1
left join cte t2
on t1.[rn] + 1 = t2.[rn];
```

Answer (score -1):

some_logical_grouping_of_data shoud define group of data which can be used for.

```
Select ID, stepname, arrival_date, duedate, 
LEAD ( arrival_date) OVER ( partition by "some_logical_grouping_of_data" order by ID) as completion_date
from table;
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a bad idea to join data based on String suffixes. I assume that `step1` always has ID `1`, `step13` always has ID `13` and so on. Then you can do something like

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Stepname, t1.arrival_date, t2.arrival_date as completion_date 
    FROM tablename t1 
    LEFT JOIN tablename t2 on t1.ID + 1 = t2.ID;
```